# What does the notation $U\mathfrak{sl}_2$ mean, and why is the $U$ written in a different typeface to the $\mathfrak{sl}$?

Tags: notation, representation-theory

A representation theory homework problem asks me to determine the finite dimensional irreducible representations and the finite dimensional indecomposable representations of $U\mathfrak{sl}_2$. I suppose this is standard notation, but I'm not sure what is meant by it.

> **Question.** What does the notation $U\mathfrak{sl}_2$ mean, and why is the $U$ written in a different typeface to the $\mathfrak{sl}$?
>
> What's the general pattern here, and how do you puzzle these things out yourself?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably means the universal enveloping algebra, though it is unusual to see it written without brackets (I would usually expect it to be written as $U(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$).

Comment: In representation theory, is $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ usually understood to be shorthand for $\mathfrak{sl}_2 (\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: @goblin Most of the time yes (at least I don't think I have seen it used differently).

Comment: @goblin Usually this is true. Sometimes, the field will be mentioned beforehand so in that case, it might not be $\mathfrak{sl}_{2}(\mathbb{C})$. The other case where it is usually different is when it is the Lie algebra of $SL_{2}$ defined as a reductive algebraic group over a field $k$, which would again usually be specified beforehand.